# Speeding up finding the longest continuous sequence/run of values

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray, era5

I have 30 years masked dataset containing values for heatwave observed days. I want to calculate the longest heat wave event occurrence in each grid cell. The below provided code works fine when I slice the dataset for one year and it takes 2 or 3 minutes to provide the result. However, 30 years data, even after one hour, it continues to process. Can anyone solve the problem?

ff is the xarray.DataArray which contains three dimension = 't2m' time: 10958 latitude: 27 longitude: 21

```
fs = hw.where(hw.rolling(time=3).count()==3).sel(time=slice('1991','2020'))
ff = fs

fs
output:
_xarray.DataArray' t2m' time: 10958 latitude: 27 longitude: 21_
_array([[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan], 
          [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan], 
          [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],

is_heatwave = fs > 0

is_heatwave
ouput:
xarray.DataArray't2m'time: 10958latitude: 27longitude: 21  
array([[[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],  
         [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],  
         [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],  


tim = 0
lati = 0
longi = 0

for t in range(1, ff.shape[0]*ff.shape[1]*ff.shape[2]):
    # Add the current value with the previous time step's value
    if np.any(ff[tim, lati, longi] > 1):
        ff[tim, lati, longi] = 1

    else:
        ff[tim, lati, longi] = 0

    longi = longi + 1
    if longi == 21:
        longi = 0
        lati = lati + 1
    
    if lati == 27:
        lati = 0
        tim = tim + 1
    
    if tim == 10959:
        break


tim = 0
lati = 0
longi = 0

for t in range(1, ff.shape[0]*ff.shape[1]*ff.shape[2]):
    # Add the current value with the previous time step's value
    if np.any(ff[tim, lati, longi] == 1):
        ff[tim, lati, longi] = ff[tim, lati, longi] + ff[tim-1, lati, longi]

    else:
        ff[tim, lati, longi] = ff[tim, lati, longi]

    longi = longi + 1
    if longi == 21:
        longi = 0
        lati = lati + 1
    
    if lati == 27:
        lati = 0
        tim = tim + 1
    
    if tim == 10959:
        break

ff_max = ff.max(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to find the longest run of True values in your array. You can do it by using this function:

```
def n_longest_consecutive(ds, dim='time'):
    ds = ds.cumsum(dim=dim) - ds.cumsum(dim=dim).where(data == 0).ffill(dim=dim).fillna(0)
    return data.max(dim=dim)
```

Before you apply the function you do have to convert the xarray dataarray into a boolean array (Only true or false values) though. This can be done like this:

```
is_heatwave = fs > 0
longest_run = n_longest_consecutive(is_heatwave)
```

Comment: Somehow this does not provide the expected result. Also, this fills the value in the final output where the values have been masked (False). 

output array example: 
array([[33.8508  , 32.670868, 34.245544, 35.90332 , 33.443146, 30.228638,
        28.841644, 27.421722, 27.786377, 29.975006, 30.531677, 30.672089,
        30.856903, 31.334747, 31.281738, 30.025177, 29.080933, 29.40976 ,
        30.988007, 32.7554  , 35.187622],

Comment: It has to be a binary/boolean array. The array can only have true or false values. So basically heatwave or no heatwave. From the output that you have pasted it doesn't look like this is the case

Comment: Yes the array is in true or false values  when I apply it to boolean array. But after applying the function the array transforms into the example array that I have provided above

Comment: Can you add an example of your input dataset to the question? If the input array is only true or false there should be no way that what I wrote returns float numbers.

Comment: I have added an example of my input dataset to the question. The output of 'fs' only contains nan (no heatwave) and float (is heatwave) values. After converting it to Boolean array, it is False (no heatwave) and True (is heatwave).

Comment: And you apply it to `is_heatwave`?

Answer (score 0):

The code is slow because of the nested loops and array manipulations. You can use vectorized operations and xarray to achieve the same result much faster. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Assuming 'hw' is your xarray.DataArray with the heatwave data
# Create a mask for heatwaves of length 3
hw_mask = (hw > 1).rolling(time=3).sum() == 3

# Select the desired time slice
ff = hw_mask.sel(time=slice('1991', '2020'))

# Convert the boolean mask to integers
ff = ff.astype(int)

# Calculate the maximum heatwave count over the entire time period
ff_max = ff.sum(dim='time').max()
```

Comment: This will not give the correct answer. It will give the total number of heatwave days in the timeframe, but not the longest continuous run of heatwave days